Storing a nested enum value in a parent enum variable
I have the following code:
class SetupVC: UIViewController {

    var isBasic:Bool = true
    var currentStep:SetupStep?
    var currentStepIndex:Int = 0

    enum SetupStep {
        case basic(BasicStep), advanced(AdvancedStep)

        enum BasicStep: CaseIterable, Equatable {
            case one, two, three
        }
    
        enum AdvancedStep: CaseIterable, Equatable {
            case one, two, three
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if isBasic == true {
            currentStep = SetupStep.BasicStep.allCases[currentStepIndex]
        } else {
            currentStep = SetupStep.AdvancedStep.allCases[currentStepIndex]
        }
        
    }
}

It produces the following error:
Cannot assign value of type 'SetupVC.SetupStep.BasicStep' to type 'SetupVC.SetupStep?'
I'm lacking some sort of basic understanding of nested enums here. It has to be possible to store a  "BasicStep" inside a "SetupStep" variable. What am I missing?
Thanks!

The variable currentStep is an optional of type SetupVC.SetupStep. This enum has two cases:

.basic, which has an associated value of type SetupVC.SetupStep.BasicStep
.advanced, which has an associated value of type SetupVC.SetupStep.AdvancedStep

So it compiles when you assign it like this:
if isBasic {
    currentStep = .basic(.allCases[currentStepIndex])
    // currentStep = SetupStep.BasicStep.allCases[currentStepIndex]
} else {
    currentStep = .advanced(.allCases[currentStepIndex])
    // currentStep = SetupStep.AdvancedStep.allCases[currentStepIndex]
}

To extract the associated value later, use a switch statement:
if let currentStep {
    switch currentStep {
    case .basic(let basicStep):
        print(basicStep)
    case .advanced(let advancedStep):
        print(advancedStep)
    }
}


I knew it had to be just a syntax issue. Thanks!

It seems to me that you are trying to have all SetupSteps available and iterate on them later.
If so, You need to define allCases for the root as well like:
enum SetupStep: CaseIterable {
    static var allCases: [SetupStep] {
        BasicStep.allCases.map { .basic($0) } +
        AdvancedStep.allCases.map { .advanced($0) }
    }

    ,,,
}

Also its better to have only one source of truth and make the currentStep computed based on the `currentStepIndex value:
var currentStep: SetupStep { .allCases[currentStepIndex] }

The you can simply switch on the currentStep value to know exactly what it is:
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    switch currentStep {
    case let .basic(basicStep):
        switch basicStep {
        case .one: // Do something
        case .two: // Do something
        case .three: // Do something
        }
    case let .advanced(advancedStep):
        switch advancedStep {
        case .four: // Do something
        case .five: // Do something
        case .six: // Do something
        }
    }
}


Thanks for the reply. In my above example I'm trying to let the ViewController know which specific "SetupStep" it is supposed to show. It could be any value from either "BasicStep" or "AdvancedStep". I'm telling it to show the first step in "BasicStep".

I think your above code would place all the values from Basic and Advanced into a joined array. Technically, this would show BasicStep.one - but what would I do if I wanted to show AdvancedStep.four?

I can see how my code above led to your conclusion based on the "one, two, three, four, five, six" values. I've updated the question so it's not confusing anymore.

Answer updated with more description and walkthrough, but still the same logic :)

I can see how your answer would work. My only issue with your answer is finding the "correct" index for the step I want to display. Let say I want to show "AdvanceStep.one" on ViewDidLoad. Using your answer, I would have to first count how many steps are in "BasicStep" to calculate what index "AdvanceStep.one" is. Am I interpreting your answer incorrectly?

What I'm getting at is the user will either see all "basic" steps or all "advanced" steps. The boolean "isBasic" determines which one is chosen on ViewDidLoad. They will never intermix.

You don't need to count, you just conform to equatable and call SetupStep.allCases.firstIndex(of: currentStep) to know the current index and +1/-1 to get the next/previous.

Sorry but I can't see why you need to nest these two enums if you don't want to keep them in a same collection. I hope this answer helps you get to your intended solution

Yes, but "allCases" includes steps from both "Basic" and "Advanced" slammed together into one. This would be problematic for me If I want to show only the "Advanced" steps. An example would be the user could press "previous" on "Advanced.one", and would be shown "Basic.three". Also when next is pressed on "Basic.three" the user would be shown "Advanced.one", when in reality all basic steps are completed, and that should be the end of it.
